# Why am I logging in as "kvm" instead of my normal username?

Tags: users, kvm-virtualization, user-management, username

One day I booted my computer and logged in and my desktop was empty. I was now in /home/kvm/Desktop. I never created this user. All my stuff is still under home/ben, so no data has been lost. kvm however does not have sudo privileges, and I am not sure how to log in as 'ben.'

The only thing I can think of is my cat typed something while I was away.

How do I begin to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can simply select my name from the dropdown menu at startup. That doesn't explain why a user was created though.

Comment: The created user is not the issue. That happens A LOT in Ubuntu. The ID of the user should have been below 1000 (could be 500? I forgot) and then that user is hidden from your input and views. You can alter the ID of user kvm if you want :)